# How to align two div in one row?

Tags: html, css

I'm beginner in HTML and trying to do some beautiful things :)
[site](http://kafedra.url.ph/)
Problem is next - in title of page I can't do some divs in a row (even using float:left). Please tell me where I was wrong :)

Comment: Which divs have the problem?

Answer (score 2):

All there answers are good, but everyone forgot the most important piece.

```
div {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

The vertical align will fix the baseline setting that will offset your divs.

Answer (score 1):

try this out

```
div {
   display: inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try adding `display: inline-block`to the style of the divs. About as much as I can say without some code.

Comment: Avoid using just display: inline as older browsers fail

Comment: @cam Which browsers fail? I'm curious about this. I've only seen issues with `display: inline-block` for older browsers. i.e. ie7. http://quirksmode.org/css/css2/display.html

Comment: Older browsers such as IE 7 IE 6, can fail if only set to display: inline; on things like divs, it will only accept it on natural items that display inline like span a etc.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
div {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

`float: left` would only float it to the left side! It won't be helpfull in keeping in a line!

For more: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display